# Drawable folder in android

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

When I want import an image in drawable folder in my project, it ask from me about 2 folder (drawable & drawable v-24 ).

I want to know what is difference between them?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topic is covered in [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources)

For your specific case, there are two folders for drawables. Drawable resource in `drawable-v24` has priority over resources with same name in `drawable` for devices with Android SDK 24+.